# asp .net navigating between different pages using angularJS in localhost

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to learn more about angularJS and I came across problem with routing.

I am developing a ASP .NET project in Visaul Studio. I am running the project in localhost on Google Chrome.

Here is how my project directory:

[image]

Here is my Index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

    <!--base href="@Url.Content("~/")" /--><!--Found it in a post. Didnt help-->
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>
    <a href="#Groups">Groups</a>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);        
        app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            //$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);            
            $routeProvider
            .when("#", {
                templateUrl: "Index.cshtml"
            })
            .when("/Groups", {
                templateUrl: '/Views/AngularViews/Groups.cshtml',
                controller: 'GroupsController'
            })
        }]);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Groups.cshtml

```
<section id="Groups_Controller" class="" ng-controller="GroupsController">
<h2>_Groups</h2>
<div>
    This is the Groups page!!!
    {{5+5}}
</div>
</section>

<script>
   function GroupsController($scope, $http, $modal, $timeout, $location) {
   };
</script>
```

This is how the page looks when I run the application.
[image]

When I click on Groups page. I get this error on the console:
[image]

Comment: your client side template page should be a `.html` page, not a `.cshtml` page, unless you want to have your server pre-parse it, and in that case you would access the server route, not the partial page directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to treat a server side `.cshtml` page as a client side `.html` partial, which won't work.  The server is actively rejecting the `.cshtml` page, because `.cshtml` pages are meant exclusively for rendering by the server, usually Razor.

You should change the file to `.html` in order for it to be rendered by Angular instead.

However, you also have another issue, in that you can't declare your Angular controller inside the partial;  The router will be trying to find the controller before the partial has been loaded, and the controller won't exist.

Also, you shouldn't use `controller:` on your route and `ng-controller` inside your partial both at the same time, since each one of these will attempt to create an instance of your controller, leading to issues with data bindings.